# CSS animation of a letter

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new at CSS. What I am going to describe is a bit confusing, but I don't see a better method. This is my humble attempt at describing my issue. I want to make a CSS animation. It should be like a sort of a flame carving out the letter 'C' (from the top end to the bottom end). So first I was trying to animate 'C' using  tags with d: (using elliptical arcs) over time. But it turns out so, that CSS considers the arcs at different percentages as arcs of different ellipses (basically the 'C' is half the arc of a single ellipse). Is there a way to like render parts of a single curve over time? Any ideas on how should I draw the flame? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 2:**

This is what I have tried:

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 52%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgb(246, 67, 67);
  stroke-width: 20px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

svg path {
  animation: carve-C 3s ease 2s 1 alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes carve-C {
  0% {
    d: path("M80,70");
  }
  25% {
    d: path("M80,70 A 19 33 0 1 0 68,85");
  }
  50% {
    d: path("M80,70 A 19 33 1 1 0 54.565,72.07969");
  }
  75% {
    d: path("M80,70 A 19 33 0 1 0 54.565,115.92");
  }
  100% {
    d: path("M80,70 A 19 33 0 1 0 68,125");
  }
}
```

```html
<h1><svg><path></path></svg></h1>
```

Instead of carving the 'C' overtime, it renders arcs of different ellipses.

[image: Initially]
[image: later stage]
[image: Finally]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far to do this? Edit your question to add the code you currently have. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: provided my code @disinfor

Comment: Add the CSS and HTML as well. We can't test with half the information either.

Comment: added CSS and HTML as well @disinfor

Comment: I'm not sure you've provided the entire relevant code: I've turned the HTML and CSS into a stack snippet for you, and there is nothing there to see if you run it.

Comment: Wait for a few seconds. There is a delay of 3 seconds. You will see how to C is rendering @domsson

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see anything, even after 30 seconds. Firefox 68.8.0esr.

Comment: @Ridayesh the code you provided does not render anything.

Comment: Its weird, as it is rendering on my screen. Maybe I can provide a picture of what I am seeing in the code snippet, else I don't know why it is running on my machine but no one else's @domsson

Comment: Hello, The code is working here. I'm a little confused regarding your question can you explain more briefly?

Comment: So, I have added the pictures now...What I want to do is like an animation in which initially there will be no 'C'. Now, imagine welding the letter 'C' on a metal with a welding flame, that is the flame will slowly carve out the 'C'. That is the animation I am looking for @MDMNauman

Comment: I think the issue is with the units of svg used in the snippet, that is since they are absolute, the 'C' is rendering out of the svg drawing frame and hence people are not able to see it @disinfor